# EF Core generates wrong SQL for group by

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I've following LINQ query in my ASP.NET Core Web API:

```
var _accountId = 101;

var textChatRecords = (from message in _dbContext.Messages
 join user in _dbContext.User on new { message.AccountId, message.UserId }
 equals new { user.AccountId, user.UserId }
 where message.AccountId == _accountId
 group new { message, user } by new { message.UserId, user.UserIdentifier } into g
 select new ReturnModel
 {
     UserId = g.FirstOrDefault().user.UserId,
     UserName = g.FirstOrDefault().user.UserName,
     UnReadCount = g.Count(x => !x.message.IsRead),
     SortID = g.Max(x => x.message.TextChatLogId),
     UserIdentifier = g.FirstOrDefault().user.UserIdentifier,
     UserFirstName = g.FirstOrDefault().user.UserName,
     UserLastName = g.FirstOrDefault().user.UserName
 }).OrderByDescending(x => x.SortID);
```

Later in the code, I'm doing

`returnModel = returnModel.Where(x => x.UserName.Contains(request.userName));`

But I found out that the `Contains()` in the above line is case sensitive even after the field in the SQL Server is case insensitive.

Which led me to the conclusion that the query is being executed on the C# side instead of in the SQL Server.
So I opened SQL Profiler and inspected the query being executed.
Which was this :

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [message].[AccountId], [message].[TextChatLogId], [message].[CommunicationLogId], [message].[CreatedBy], [message].[CreatedOn], [message].[Direction], [message].[IsRead], [message].[LastUpdatedBy], [message].[LastUpdatedOn], [message].[Message], [message].[UserId], [message].[RowVersionStamp], [user].[AccountId], [user].[UserId], [user].[AddressLine1], [user].[AddressLine2], [user].[Age], [user].[City], [user].[CreatedDate], [user].[DefaultHygenistId], [user].[DefaultLocationId], [user].[DefaultProviderId], [user].[Email], [user].[EmailNotification], [user].[FirstName], [user].[Gender], [user].[IsActive], [user].[LastName], [user].[Mobile], [user].[UserIdentifier], [user].[UserName], [user].[PhoneWithExt], [user].[PostalNotification], [user].[PreferredContactTextMedium], [user].[PreferredContactVoiceMedium], [user].[PromotionEmailNotification], [user].[RelationshipToResponsibleParty], [user].[ResponsiblePartyUserId], [user].[State], [user].[TextNotification], [user].[Type], [user].[VoiceNotification], [user].[WorkPhoneWithExt], [user].[ZipCode]
FROM [pat_eng].[Messages] AS [message]
INNER JOIN [pat_eng].[User] AS [user] ON ([message].[AccountId] = [user].[AccountId]) AND ([message].[UserId] = [user].[UserId])
WHERE [message].[AccountId] = @___accountId_0
ORDER BY [message].[UserId], [user].[UserIdentifier]',N'@___accountId_0 int',@___accountId_0=101
```

This SQL Query doesn't have any `group by` or `Contains` that I wrote in C# code.

Why My LINQ is translated into the wrong SQL?

Comment: LINQ isn't SQL, nor a replacement for SQL. It's the *ORM's* job to create joins from entity relations. If you have to use `join` in LINQ it means there are missing relations in the model. As for the query itself, `group new { message, user }` is trying to create a *new* object, as if it were a SELECT. How is EF Core going to translate this into SQL?

Comment: As for the problem itself, an unfortunate EF Core "feature" is client query evaluation for the parts it can't translate into SQL. The query before `group new {...}` can be translated into SQL. The results are then grouped on the server.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Did you mean grouped on the client?

Comment: EF Core has problems with this type of query, unlike EF 6.x, what version of EF Core are you using? EF Core 2.1 did better with this, EF Core 3.0 may catch up with EF 6. Or may not.

Comment: @NetMage (facepalm)